# What is the plane gradient?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

My professor recently used the following phrase "the unknown 3D point is in a plane whose gradient is $(a,b,c)^T$". I can't seem to place his terminology anywhere on the internet. What does he mean by the gradient of the plane?

Answer (score 1):

A plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is implicitly defined by 
$$ F(x,y,z) =  ax+by+cz = \delta. $$

The points $(x,y,z)$ that verify this equation all lie in the plane perpendicular to the vector $(a,b,c)$.

The gradient of $F$ is just $\nabla F(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the distance part. Aren't a,b,c, and $\delta$ constants? Surely all points on a plane aren't a constant distance from the origin, correct?

Comment: You are right. What I meant to say was, that the plane has distance $\frac{\delta}{\|(a,b,c)\|}$ from the origin, that is, the minimum distance of all points in the plane to the origin.

Comment: Also see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane).